# Calculating shape and scale Parameter using fitdistr() But grouping by Tag and code wise [Reliability Modelling using Weibull Distribution technique]

Tags: r, reliability, weibull

Hello Every One Earlier to this Post i have posted the reproducible Example it was working fine with that reproducible data , But i tried with the actual data it was giving an error `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : optimization failed` so here is a glimpse of the actual which i am getting an error,i am clueless about the error because if it is working with reproducible data it should run exactly the same.I have also pasted a sample code below.

```
Tag= c("Z52" ,"Z52","Z66 - ZARK II","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z82 V3","Z82 V3","Z52","Z52","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z82 V3"        ,"Z88","Z88","Z88","Z52","Z82 V3","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z52","Z88","Z88","Z52" ,"Z88","Z82 V3","Z88","Z82 V3","Z82 V3","Z82 V3","Z88","Z88","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z88","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z88"           ,"Z52","Z52","Z52","Z52","Z52","Z52","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II","Z88","Z82 V3","Z82 V3","Z88","Z88","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z52","Z52","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z88","Z82 V3","Z88","Z88","Z66 - ZARK II","Z82 V3","Z82 V3" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z82 V3","Z88","Z88","Z82 V3","Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z88"           ,"Z66 - ZARK II" ,"Z66 - ZARK II","Z66 - ZARK II" )
code = c(   270 ,270 ,269 ,135 ,135 ,135 ,331 ,331 ,331 ,136 ,270 ,269 ,269 ,283 ,135 ,135 ,331 ,331 ,432 ,432 ,283 ,270 ,283 ,135 ,135 ,331 ,136  ,94 ,125 ,136 ,254 ,103 ,283 ,214 ,214 ,214 ,283 ,149  ,51
             ,269 ,269 ,135  ,94 ,136 ,127 ,270 ,270 ,270 ,270 ,270 ,270 ,51 ,269 ,269 ,364 ,283 ,283  ,94 ,364 ,214  ,51 ,213 ,270  ,51 ,269 ,270 ,269 ,269 ,135 ,135 ,135 ,135 ,270 ,103 ,127 ,103  ,10  ,10
             ,283 ,283 ,212 ,103 ,250 ,137 ,137 ,137  ,10  ,10  ,95 ,103 ,269 ,269 ,270 ,269 ,269 ,269  ,10 ,137 ,137 ,137)
life = c(  1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1645 ,1646 ,1646 ,1646 ,1646 ,1646 ,1646 ,1646 ,1646 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1647 ,1648 ,1648 ,1648 ,1648
               ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1649 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1650 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651
               ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1651 ,1652 ,1652 ,1652 ,1653 ,1653 ,1653 ,1653 ,1653 ,1653 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654
               ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1654 ,1655 ,1655 ,1655)
```

**R Code:**

```
df=data.frame(Tag=Tag,Err_code=code,Life=life)

library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
by_ME<- group_by(df,Tag,Err_code)
fg1 <- summarise(by_ME,
                 shape_P=fitdistr(Life, "weibull")$estimate[1],
                 scale_P=fitdistr(Life, "weibull")$estimate[2],
                 n=n())
```

**Error Observed**
`Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : optimization failed`

Comment: @RichardTelford I have eidited the variable as per data frame

Comment: remove the `df$` - does it work?

Comment: no it dosent i have tried it earlier

Comment: What error do you get then? Seems to work for me

Comment: Hey @RichardTelford its working for me as well , sometime it dosent take , and now it calculating perfectly as per my given codes ,the only thing i doudth is before calling the function `firdistr()` all the numbers in failure should be arrange in ascending order ,but groupwise [sys,alarm]. I am not sure about this !! Can you plz guide me on this

Comment: Hey @RichardTelford i am getting error of `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : optimization failed` when i am trying on actual data